# Cross-compileing for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile [BindToInterface](https://github.com/JsBergbau/BindToInterface)

```
baka$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bindToInterface.c -o bindToInterface.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE


bindToInterface.c:3:10: fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <sys/socket.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I guess i need to install a package to solve it but I couldn't find the name

Comment: It's not possible to compile that program for `none-eabi`. `none-eabi` has no `sys/socket.h`, it has no kernel. You have to implement those functions yourself if you want them. Also, I do not fully understand why would you compile a program to "bind to interface" if you are compiling for `none-eabi` target - there are no "interface"s there.

Comment: yes, basically any library calls you want (none-eabi or other) for cross compiling you need the libraries and header files for that target and then point the cross compiler at them.   Include path, library path, libraries or objects, etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, you're right I picked the wrong toolchain.